# Access Azure KeyVault from all executors in Databricks, can be done?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks, azure-keyvault

I suspect that this can't be done out of the box and want to know a way of doing this. I am trying to do it without success. So far I have tried this:

Based on this [link](https://able.bio/patrickcording/sharing-objects-in-spark--58x4gbf#one-instance-per-executor), I have created a Class and an object (companion and not, both ways) for ciphering text in every worker of the cluster. It has some third party libraries implied so that's why I can't use serialization. And for initializing its values, I take some of them from an Azure Keyvault (this seems to work on driver but not in executors).

When I execute the cells declaring the class and the object it runs ok, this I think is because its the driver here, and it initializes ok its values from the KeyVault. But when using it for cipher a table I get an exception.

In my code I have a Spark UDF that makes use of that class for ciphering, like this:

```
val encrypt_long = udf[Long, Long](plain_long => {
  val plain_texted = plain_long.toString
  val plain_bytes = AESFPE.instance.numericAlphabetMapper.convertToIndexes(plain_texted.toCharArray)
  val cipher_chars = AESFPE.instance.numericAlphabetMapper.convertToChars(AESFPE.instance.encrypt(AESFPE.instance.cipher, AESFPE.instance.sKey, AESFPE.instance.tweak, AESFPE.instance.numericRadix, plain_bytes))
  new String(cipher_chars).toLong
}
```

And calling this UDF I get this exception:

```
Job aborted due to stage failure: [FAILED_EXECUTE_UDF] Failed to execute user defined function ($read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$Lambda$9794/149626391: (bigint) => bigint).
Caused by: [FAILED_EXECUTE_UDF] Failed to execute user defined function ($read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$Lambda$9794/149626391: (bigint) => bigint).
Caused by: NullPointerException:
```

With this cause for the exception, it seems to me that the problem is in the initialization of the sKey member of the class (which is the one taking values from Azure KeyVault):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at $line1b09d7456fac420b8b404a7387bae2f8123.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$AESFPE.sKey$lzycompute(command-4335102701464202:16)
    at $line1b09d7456fac420b8b404a7387bae2f8123.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$AESFPE.sKey(command-4335102701464202:16)
    at $line1b09d7456fac420b8b404a7387bae2f8127.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.$anonfun$encrypt_long$1(command-4335102701464206:22)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction1$mcJJ$sp.apply(JFunction1$mcJJ$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:761)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:464)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$executeWrite$3(FileFormatWriter.scala:316)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.$anonfun$runTask$3(ResultTask.scala:75)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.$anonfun$runTask$1(ResultTask.scala:75)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:174)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.$anonfun$run$5(Task.scala:142)
    at com.databricks.unity.EmptyHandle$.runWithAndClose(UCSHandle.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.$anonfun$run$1(Task.scala:142)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$13(Executor.scala:904)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1713)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:907)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:761)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

There is a need here to have some of the same value configs in every worker for the cipher class, so they can encrypt and decrypt with the same configuration.

As another way around, but not being a valid solution, I have made it work hardcoding these configuration values in the cipher class. But this is not valid because its not safe to have that kind of configuration in code, it must be in a place like a KeyVault. Using the KeyVault and serializing the cipher class is not an option because it has third-party code and throws not serializable exception.

Comment: Apologies if it is not relevant, but will reading the keyvault contents via a secret scope work ? Now it should be accessible from everywhere ? [secret_scope docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/secrets/secret-scopes)

Comment: I already retrieve the values from the KeyVault using a secret scope, created in Databricks and backed in Azure SecretVault. From my tests it works on the driver but not on the execturos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround for the problem to be able to use the secrets from the KeyVault in all the execturos. I only tested so far this in the notebooks, I want to try later in a JAR job.

First here is a [link to the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/databricks-utils#limitations) that highlights some limitations of dbutils API, the very one that Databricks recommends to read secrets.

Now the workaround:

Not being able to use dbutils from execturos, these are the steps I followed to bring the values of a KeyVault secret to an object initialization in every executor:

1. Reference a secret in an evnironmental variable, [like this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/secrets/secrets#--reference-a-secret-in-an-environment-variable).
2. Prior to any other cell execution, set values in the same variable names from the driver, but in the executor´s environments, like this:

   spark.conf.set("spark.executorEnv.anon_pwd", sys.env("anon_pwd"))
   spark.conf.set("spark.executorEnv.anon_salt", sys.env("anon_salt"))
   spark.conf.set("spark.executorEnv.anon_tweak", sys.env("anon_tweak"))
3. Use the UDF function that makes use of the singleton object in every executor.